# How to concatenate lists in Dataframe after grouping

Tags: python, pandas

After grouping a dataframe the result is that I have a list in each row of the dataframe.

```
                                                 Id
0   [GSTE00057]
1   [LOKH18675]
2   [LWWSD61, PTZW6, VCVCD064, AFER53423]
3   [KJHZ64534]
4   [GDHSGD88888]
5   [FSDAE00003]
6   [IHUGZF051, ZGGTHZ0052, PRRDSE00053, PUITZRT00087]
```

How can I make one list out of it?

I tried:

```
.apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x.values).tolist()).reset_index()
```

but I get :

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'
```

desired output:

```
[GSTE00057, LOKH18675,LWWSD61, PTZW6, VCVCD064, AFER53423, KJHZ64534.........]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use itertools.chain:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

# toy data
data = [["GSTE00057"],
        ["LOKH18675"],
        ["LWWSD61", "PTZW6", "VCVCD064", "AFER53423"],
        ["KJHZ64534"],
        ["GDHSGD88888"],
        ["FSDAE00003"],
        ["IHUGZF051", "ZGGTHZ0052", "PRRDSE00053", "PUITZRT00087"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[e] for e in data], columns=["Id"])

# concatenate
res = list(chain.from_iterable(df["Id"]))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['GSTE00057', 'LOKH18675', 'LWWSD61', 'PTZW6', 'VCVCD064', 'AFER53423', 'KJHZ64534', 'GDHSGD88888', 'FSDAE00003', 'IHUGZF051', 'ZGGTHZ0052', 'PRRDSE00053', 'PUITZRT00087']
```

Or as an alternative:

```
res = np.concatenate(df["Id"]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas methods: [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`pd.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html)

```py
df["ID"].explode().tolist()
```

Outputs:

```
['GSTE00057', 'LOKH18675', 'LWWSD61', 'PTZW6', 'VCVCD064', 'AFER53423', 'KJHZ64534', 'GDHSGD88888', 'FSDAE00003', 'IHUGZF051', 'ZGGTHZ0052', 'PRRDSE00053', 'PUITZRT00087']
```